# Solving Recursion With Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Say a linear recursion has the form: $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+2^{n-2}$, I know it would be possible to solve it with $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ and $a_n=2^{n-2}$ and then combine the two using some coefficient A, B.

However, is there any proof to this will always work for linear recursions? (to separate and then combine it) I have seen this method being using a few times on math exchange.

Comment: Dob't you mean $a_n=2^{n+2}$ not $a_n=2^n?$

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: if it helps with my question, then yes, i do not remember the exact time when this technique is used sorry

Comment: The difference is that $a_n=2^{n+2}$ is a solution to the problem, and $a_n=2^n$ is not.  Substitute them into the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to the way you solve linear differential equations with constant coefficients, and for a good reason... We can identify a basis for the space of solutions, which depends on the roots of the polynomial characteristic.

In this case, the characteristic polynomial is $p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 -\lambda -1$ and the solution can be written as $a_n = h_n + p_n$, where $h_n$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation $h_n = h_{n-1} + h_{n-2}$ and $p_n$ is a particular solution of our equation.

The roots of the characteristic polynomial are $\lambda = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and so we have that
$$
h_n = c_1 \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+ c_2 \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
$$

Regarding the particular solution, one usual option is to try something "similar" to the RHS, in this case we can try $p_n= c 2^{n}$. If we plug that into the equation, we can see that $p_n = 2^{n}$ is a solution to the equation.

Finally, the general solution to our equation is given by

$$
a_ n = 2^{n}  +c_1 \left( \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+ c_2 \left( \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n
$$.

Comment: is there any proof that i can combine hn and pn? like solving hn can be proven by matrix decompsition

Comment: @jamesblack It is the same standard proof used for instance with linear systems, when you prove that the solution to a linear system is always the sum of the general solution of $Ax = 0$ with a particular solution of $Ax=b$. This is just related to the underlying linear structure.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "always work."  The method is

1) Solve the homogeneous recurrence.  (The recurrence without the $2^n$).  This involves finding the roots of a polynomial, which you can do if the degree inn't two high.  In a case like this, the degree is $2$, so you can do it.

2) Guess a solution to the inhomogeneous recurrence.  For some functions on the right-hand side, there is an easy way to do it.  For example, if instead of $2^n$ we had $3^n$ of $n^2$ there is a well-known way to find a solution.  If it were $\sin{n}$ I, at least have no way to go about it.

3) Combine the general solution and the guess to satisfy the initial conditions.  This can be done, in principal, but the result may be too complicate to be worth the effort.

There are some nice slides at http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf which include proofs of the theorems.

Comment: yes, i learned that step 1 can be proven by matrices decompsition and 2 can be guessed; however what is the proof for step number 3 s.t. this works? is that included in the slides

Comment: @saulspatz This process will surely work at least if the RHS is itself the solution of an homogeneous difference equation.

Comment: @PierreCarre Can you elaborate a little on that?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @jamesblack Look at proposition $4$ in the slides.

Comment: @saulspatz These equations can be written in the form $P(\delta) a_n = f_n$, where $P(\delta) $ is a polynomial of the operator $\delta$ (usually the shift or the difference operator). If you are able to find a polynomial $Q(\delta)$ such that $Q(\delta) f_n =0$, you can reduce the initial equation  to the homogeneous equation $Q(\delta) P(\delta) a_n = 0$. Once you solve this last equation, the particular solution will correspond to the terms that are not include in the solution of the initial homogeneous equation (and whose coefficients must be computed).

Comment: Thank you.  I'd never looked at it this way.